# Ubuntu 15.10 is Mirroring my monitors and the settings are unchangeable

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, multiple-monitors

Just to preface, this is the most annoyed I have ever been in my life and I'm kind of on the verge of a mental breakdown because my dual monitors are ABSOLUTELY ESSENTIAL in my homework filled life.

I have Ubuntu 15.10 and up until today my dual monitor setup worked just fine. I booted it up today to find that my monitors are no longer independant; they are mirrored. Needless to say, this is completely useless. I first attempted to go into the settings and fix this, but it only shows one monitor like below.

[Of course it doesn't detect it, why would it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2XUT.png)

Obviously I tried to hit detect monitors, but that didn't do anything. It didnt show a loading icon, and it didnt open any other windows.

This is the basic picture, which brings me to my question:

**How in the mother@%$#ing world do I fix this and get my dual monitors back?**

(preferably without reinstalling linux)

> > > **ABOUT MY SYSTEM**
> >
> > HARDWARE
>
> Processor -  AMD FX-8350 Black Edition Vishera 8-Core
>
> Graphics - AMD Radeon R9 290x
>
> Motherboard - ASUS M5A99FX PRO R2.0 AM3
>
> > Software
>
> Ubuntu - 15.10
>
> Graphics Driver - Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii Pro: Radeon 290
>
> > > > **WHAT I'VE TRIED**
> >
> > **#1**
> >     I tried reinstalling my driver for my graphics card because I saw the
> >     [system description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CWtX.png)
> >     and I thought that it wasn't using my graphics card (which is weird because I'm pretty sure both my monitors are plugged into that)
> >     but that wasn't it (I'm 98% sure)
> >
> > **#2**
> >     I tried a simple system update but once again I am rejected
> >     by the software updater

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)/dists/vivid/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)/dists/vivid/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
```

I tried fixing that but I quickly got lost in many random forums and became mentally overwhelmed.

Another quick question: will reinstalling 15.04 or 15.10 help? because I'm all ears at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to look harder and I found the answer.
[Revert to open source graphics drivers - options greyed out 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/587582/revert-to-open-source-graphics-drivers-options-greyed-out-14-04)
it was a broken driver
the second answer is the one that worked